# Accumulo: Username or Password is Invalid issue

Tags: accumulo

So I have configured and initialized accumulo as given in the [Accumulo User Manual](https://accumulo.apache.org/user_manual_1.3-incubating/Administration.html).

In the `conf/accumulo-site.xml`, I set my `trace.user` to `accumulo_tracer`, and I also create a system user with the same name. Additionally, I store the password in the same file under `trace.token.property.password` property.

However, after `./bin/start-all.sh`, everything starts up fine, including the accumulo UI. But the following error is displayed in the `logs/tracer_localhost.log` file.

```
2015-05-28 10:58:46,229 [watcher.MonitorLog4jWatcher] INFO : Enabled log-forwarding
2015-05-28 10:58:46,254 [server.Accumulo] INFO : tracer starting
2015-05-28 10:58:46,254 [server.Accumulo] INFO : Instance 48f5f9cf-f08d-4736-b504-335b044a2d88
2015-05-28 10:58:46,255 [server.Accumulo] INFO : Data Version 6
2015-05-28 10:58:46,255 [server.Accumulo] INFO : Attempting to talk to zookeeper
2015-05-28 10:58:46,430 [server.Accumulo] INFO : ZooKeeper connected and initialized, attempting to talk to HDFS
2015-05-28 10:58:46,430 [server.Accumulo] INFO : Connected to HDFS
2015-05-28 10:58:46,432 [watcher.MonitorLog4jWatcher] INFO : Changing monitor log4j address to localhost:4560
2015-05-28 10:58:46,433 [watcher.MonitorLog4jWatcher] INFO : Enabled log-forwarding
2015-05-28 10:58:46,510 [watcher.MonitorLog4jWatcher] INFO : Set watch for Monitor Log4j watcher
2015-05-28 10:58:46,638 [tracer.TraceServer] INFO : Waiting to checking/create the trace table.
org.apache.accumulo.core.client.AccumuloSecurityException: Error BAD_CREDENTIALS for user accumulo_tracer - Username or Password is Invalid
    at org.apache.accumulo.core.client.impl.ServerClient.execute(ServerClient.java:65)
    at org.apache.accumulo.core.client.impl.ConnectorImpl.<init>(ConnectorImpl.java:66)
    at org.apache.accumulo.server.client.HdfsZooInstance.getConnector(HdfsZooInstance.java:156)
    at org.apache.accumulo.tracer.TraceServer.<init>(TraceServer.java:201)
    at org.apache.accumulo.tracer.TraceServer.main(TraceServer.java:303)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.accumulo.start.Main$1.run(Main.java:141)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: ThriftSecurityException(user:accumulo_tracer, code:BAD_CREDENTIALS)
    at org.apache.accumulo.core.client.impl.thrift.ClientService$authenticate_result$authenticate_resultStandardScheme.read(ClientService.java:15613)
    at org.apache.accumulo.core.client.impl.thrift.ClientService$authenticate_result$authenticate_resultStandardScheme.read(ClientService.java:15591)
    at org.apache.accumulo.core.client.impl.thrift.ClientService$authenticate_result.read(ClientService.java:15535)
    at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:78)
    at org.apache.accumulo.core.client.impl.thrift.ClientService$Client.recv_authenticate(ClientService.java:500)
    at org.apache.accumulo.core.client.impl.thrift.ClientService$Client.authenticate(ClientService.java:486)
    at org.apache.accumulo.core.client.impl.ConnectorImpl$1.execute(ConnectorImpl.java:69)
    at org.apache.accumulo.core.client.impl.ConnectorImpl$1.execute(ConnectorImpl.java:66)
    at org.apache.accumulo.core.client.impl.ServerClient.executeRaw(ServerClient.java:100)
    at org.apache.accumulo.core.client.impl.ServerClient.execute(ServerClient.java:63)
    ... 10 more
2015-05-28 10:58:47,469 [server.Accumulo] WARN : System swappiness setting is greater than ten (60) which can cause time-sensitive operations to be delayed.  Accumulo is time sensitive because it needs to maintain distributed lock agreement.
```

Any help or guidance where I might have missed something, would be very helpful!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a system user with that name. What you need is to create an *Accumulo* user with that name. You can do this in the accumulo shell as the (Accumulo) root user `$ACCUMULO_HOME/bin/accumulo shell -u root`. You'll also need to grant the user the table permission to create tables. See `help grant` in the shell to learn how to set the CREATE_TABLE system permission for that user.

Answer (score 0):

So here's what solved my issue: a fresh *init*!!

So during the *init* phase, I give a password for the *root* user and the same password I am supposed to mention in the *conf/accumulo-site.xml*

```
<property>
  <name>instance.secret</name>
  <value>your_own_secret_password</value>
  <description>A secret unique to a given instance that all servers must know in order to communicate with one another.
  Change it before initialization. To
  change it later use ./bin/accumulo org.apache.accumulo.server.util.ChangeSecret --old [oldpasswd] --new [newpasswd],
  and then update this file.
  </description>
</property>
```

After that everything just worked like a charm. Hope that helped. Post any queries, would be happy to help.